# Overflow when calculating a const in VBA

Tags: vba, constants, overflow

This declaration causes an overflow in VBA:

```
Const OVERFLOWS As Long = 10 * 60 * 60
```

whereas setting the value directly is fine:

```
Const COMPILES_OK As Long = 36000
```

How do you persuade VBA to treat literal integers as longs?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `long` suffix `&` to at least one number:

```
Const OVERFLOWS As Long = 10& * 60 * 60
```

Note that using the `CLNG` function to convert the values to `long` will not work, because VBA does not allow assigning the return value of a function to a constant.

Comment: The reason for the problem is that the default number type in Access is Integer. I believe that type declaration characters are less used, and Clng etc, as suggested by dbb is to be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191713 is a nice summary of the type declaration characters available in VBA / VB4-6.

Answer (score 4):

For those who find the & symbol a bit esoteric, an alternative is to use the CLNG function which converts a number to long

```
Const OVERFLOWS As Long = CLNG(10) * 60 * 60
```

you could then do a similar thing for a Single constant

```
Const OVERFLOWS As Single = CSNG(10) * 60 * 60
```

Comment: This would be great, if only it would work, but it doesn't, as noted in the answer by "xsl".

Answer (score 3):

The type character can also be appended to literals : Const OVERFLOWS As Long = (10& * 60 * 60)
(one is suffucient actually because of the way the VBA engine evaluates the expression).